# Button shifting on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, button, hover, position

I've got a problem with my menu buttons shifting whenever I'm hovering over them with my mouse. Once I've done that they're all in place. When I press F5 to relaod the page the buttons are already in place. The problem does not occur in IE8. I'm using Chrome (updated).

CSS:

```
div.header_container
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
}

div.header
{
    margin-top: 54px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
}

div.logo
{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

div.menu
{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 58px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

div.menu ul
{

}

div.menu ul li
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    list-style-image:url("../images/menu_block.jpg");
}

div.menu ul li:hover
{
    list-style-image:url("../images/menu_block_mo.png");
}

div.menu ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'CalibriRegular';
}
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header_container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#" title="Video Photo Editing Graphics | Stefanvlemmix.nl"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="./index.html">Start</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle

Comment: @Rich He already provided the code - just cut/paste.. Could have already made one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Z3Ra/ Done :)

Comment: It's got something to do with the images you are attaching on hover. Will be hard to debug without the actual images.

Comment: The images used in the fiddle are the images I'm using, just uploaded to imgur. But they're exactly the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man,

You are using another image on HOVER. That hover image is not loaded initially and when you mouse hover on it - then it starts loading hence you have that shifting on first hover.

You should be using CSS Sprite to overcome these kinds of issues.

**EDIT**

OR, use HTML characters and CSS generated contents (`:after, :before`) for this. Just change the color on hover.

All you need:

```
div.menu ul li
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    list-style:none;
}

.menu li:before {
    display:inline-block;
    content: "\25A0";
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

div.menu ul li:hover:before
{
    color:red;
}
```

And done. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/vQjMX/